# dc.js: using dc.dataCount counts in other d3 charts on page

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

In dc.js I'm displaying the number of filtered and total rows with dc.dataCount:

```
dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count", "charts")
    .dimension(data_cf)
    .group(all);
```

and

```
<div class="dc-data-count">
  <strong class="filter-count"></strong> selected out of <strong class="total-count"></strong> records
```

On the same page, I have a d3 donut chart that I've drawn. Within this chart I'd like to display the filter-count (which updates as filters are applied), as well as other calculations like the sum of a value in the current selection. Given that dc.dataCount is accessed by a div class, I don't know how to access the number to place precisely in my donut chart.

How can I pass values from dc.dataCount or some other grouping into a d3 object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a renderlet on the donut chart that just reads the values you need, and adds them. [Renderlets](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#renderletrenderletfunction) run after the chart has rendered, so there is a slight delay, but it shouldn't be too disturbing for this use.

As for how to get the numbers, there is no magic to the dataCount widget; it's just reading crossfilter values:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/src/data-count.js#L77

So you can add text elements to the svg using `dimension.size()` and `group.value()` in the same way.